# using update with multiple select statments

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 update opportunitysrcfact set [Last_Amount]=  (select  c.amount from

 (select a.amount,b.id from

   ( Select * from OpportunitySrcFact    where fiscalweekqtr = '2013 Q3 5')  a
   inner join 
   ( Select * from opportunitysrcfact    where fiscalweekqtr = '2013 Q3 6')  b
  on a.id = b.id 
   where a.amount != b.amount )  c )
   where opportunitysrcfact.id = c.id and opportunitysrcfact.fiscalweekqtr ='2013 Q3 6'
```

Above is the query which gives an error coz c.id is a multilevel identifier and cant be used in th last where clause. 
I needto update the selected amount in the row with the given opportunity ID

Comment: Why dont you just select out your value into a variable, then set it in the update statement?

Comment: i dont want to include the parameters due to some dependencies , thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using sql server you can use a 'With' clause with an update statement.

TRY THIS:

```
 with c as
   (
    select a.amount as amount,b.id as id from

       ( Select * from OpportunitySrcFact    where fiscalweekqtr = '2013 Q3 5')  a
        inner join 
       ( Select * from opportunitysrcfact    where fiscalweekqtr = '2013 Q3 6')  b
        on a.id = b.id 
        and a.amount != b.amount 
   )
   update opportunitysrcfact 
   set Last_Amount=  c.amount
   from opportunitysrcfact inner join c
   on opportunitysrcfact.id = c.id and opportunitysrcfact.fiscalweekqtr ='2013 Q3 6';
```